# How to automatize iPhone app generation?

Tags: ios, iphone, build-automation

Ok, we wish to do something along the lines of... this:

1. Someone enters our site, goes through some forms, registers an account, then a script is executed on the server.
2. This script will more or less do the following:

   - Create a folder within the root of our hosting.
   - Clone a repository which contains a "white-label" iPhone project, with all the code and associated files. The clone will be stored in the aforementioned folder.
   - Some configuration files will be added to said folder as well (JSON files).

Now, here's the tricky part... We don't know how to approach this:

- The script needs to -somehow- be able to automatically generate a fully functioning, valid iPhone app (an .ipa file, I assume, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) using the files provided in the folder where the repository clone was stored.

Important stuff to take into account:

- The app files in the repository do not specify a customized name for the application (the one below the app icon in iPhones...). Instead, it comes with a generic name, which must NOT be present in the app once this "automated app generation process" finishes. Instead, it must use an application name contained in a configuration file (a JSON file, that is).
- The "finished app" must have our distribution profile included, and it must be codesigned accordingly.

**So basically**, we wish to have a server script that ultimately *automatizes the process one usually goes through when using Xcode to generate a finished iPhone application*. This is because our current business project consists of a white-label app that is "customized" for each one of our clients, and we wish to be as time-effective as possible, avoiding manual processes when we can.

Any ideas? Could this be done? What would be needed?

Comment: You basically just want to build an iOS Xcode project from the command line. There are plenty of existing questions and google results which can help you with this.

Comment: agreed. xcode actually uses a command line to build your project.  you can do this yourself, check the results of the command then pull the ipa from the tree where it is created.  There is a WWDC video on use xcode command line stuff - I think it is in 2012 library.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following terminal command for generating a build for one of my project hope it could be of any help to you

From terminal navigate to the folder where `Projectname.xcodeproj` file is present and then following command.

```
xcodebuild -project DummyCam.xcodeproj/ -configuration Release CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="Path to directory where build will be copied" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${DIST_PROVISONING_PROFILE}"
```

Comment: `PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${DIST_PROVISONING_PROFILE}"`


What goes in "${DIST_PROVISONING_PROFILE}"? Could you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: I mean, obviously it refers to a profile, but do I use a name, or a file route...?

Comment: @EmmanuelFiguerola: Sorry dont have full info about `PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${DIST_PROVISONING_PROFILE}"` It might point out to default provisioning profile. I tried this command long ago, found some where on my machine.